# Join on same table in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table in Hive with the following columns

```
userid                  string
attribute_name          string
attribute_value         string
```

The `attribute_name` can be a value like age, gender etc. The attribute value is the value for that name, say M for gender. What I want is a table, that has for each userid, all the values aggregated for a particular attribute_name. e.g., if this is a sample table

```
userid    attribute_name    attribute_value
1000      gender            M
1000      city              Perth
1000      city              Singapore
1001      gender            F
1001      city              Tokyo
1001      gender            M
1002      city              Bombay
```

I'd like to get

```
1000      {M}     {Perth, Singapore}
1001      {F,M}   {Tokyo}
```

The braces are for clarity only.

I can get two individual table and possibly then do a join, however I am trying to do it in a single step

```
select userid, count (DISTINCT table.attribute_value) as numgender, collect_set(table.attribute_value) as genders
```

from table where attribute_name == "gender" GROUP BY table.userid

and similarly for cities can it be done in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      userid
           ,concat_ws(',',collect_list (case when attribute_name = 'gender' then attribute_value end)) as genders
           ,concat_ws(',',collect_list (case when attribute_name = 'city'   then attribute_value end)) as cities

from        mytable

group by    userid
;
```

---

```
+--------+---------+-----------------+
| userid | genders |     cities      |
+--------+---------+-----------------+
|   1000 | M       | Perth,Singapore |
|   1001 | F,M     | Tokyo           |
|   1002 |         | Bombay          |
+--------+---------+-----------------+
```

---

In order to filter out userid without gender -

```
having count (case when attribute_name = 'gender' then 1 end) > 0
```

Comment: What if I do not want rows where genders is empty, as in 1002 in the above example. How would that be filtered out? Thanks.